# C# Excel COM Interop throwing exception "Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC"

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

**Scope:**

I am implementing an automated report generation using both [epplus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) and Excel COM Interop for doing so. Since there are tasks that EPPlus can't achieve, i have found myself forced to use Excel COM to cover all the missing features from EPPlus.

Basically the way i am working is:

1 - Execute a query on my database

2 - Dump the result into a "base_sheet" (with headers)

3 - Create the pivot tables using the "base_sheets". This always works, since i have been using this tactic for quite a while.

**Interop Usage:**

The whole flow can be achieved by using EPPlus only (which gives me no problems), with exception of Pre-Selecting the Pivot Table Filters. (Like the image bellow shows, instead of showing "All" elements, i only want the ones the match "PG", for this filter).

[image: Example of Pivot AutoSelected Filter]

**Problem:**

An error named `Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC` is raised uppon calling a method regarding pivot tables (built into Excel Interop).

**Some Code Sample:**

-- Sample #1

```
// Creating Interop Object
_excelApp = new Application();
        _workbook = _excelApp.Workbooks.Open(filePath, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing,true); // The last "True" arguments avoids "corruption error"
```

-- Sample #2

```
// Disposing Object
public void Dispose ()
    {
        _workbook.Save  ();
        _workbook.Close ();
        _excelApp.Quit  ();
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject (_workbook);
    }
```

-- Sample #3

```
// Iterating over worksheet and their pivot tables
foreach (Worksheet sheet in _workbook.Sheets)
        {
            switch (sheet.Name)
            {
                case "ACTDIAXDIA":

                    foreach (PivotTable pivotTable in sheet.PivotTables ())
                    {
                        pivotTable.PivotCache().MissingItemsLimit = XlPivotTableMissingItems.xlMissingItemsNone;
                        pivotTable.PivotCache().Refresh();

                        // Settting Pivot Table Outline Layout
                        pivotTable.RowAxisLayout (XlLayoutRowType.xlOutlineRow);

                        // Retrieving Filter instance
                        PivotField pivotField = (PivotField) pivotTable.PageFields ("TIPO_MOVIMENTO");

                        ToggleFieldVisibility (pivotField, "PG", true);
                        ToggleFieldVisibility (pivotField, "AC", false);
                        ToggleFieldVisibility (pivotField, "AJ", false);                            
                        ToggleFieldVisibility (pivotField, "RX", false);

                        pivotField = (PivotField)pivotTable.PageFields ("TIPO_COBRANCA");

                        ToggleFieldVisibility (pivotField, "ACT", true);
                        ToggleFieldVisibility (pivotField, "TC", false);
                        ToggleFieldVisibility (pivotField, "DEMAIS", false);
                    }
                break; // Code goes on, but its not needed for this demonstration
```

This is the line the raises me the error:

```
// Retrieving Filter instance
PivotField pivotField = (PivotField) pivotTable.PageFields ("TIPO_MOVIMENTO");
```

**Closing:**

After some extensive research on the web, by the error message, i usually find that it is caused by using Zero based ranges, instead of starting with "1" when creating "Range" instances, but that's not my case, so i really don't know how to proceed here.

**Update One:**

Code of my Interop Wrapper Class + Usage: http://pastebin.com/B59QvZhf

I can't post a sample Report (.xlsx file) here, since it contains sensitive data.

I am using :

Microsoft.Office.Core Version 2.5.0.0

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel Version 14.0.0.0

Visual Studio 2012 and 2013 Ultimate

Comment: can you try changing your .Open method call with something like this and see if it's perhaps a `Conversion` Issue
`var _workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(filePath, 0, true, 5, emptStr, emptStr, true,
XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);`

Comment: EmpStr = String.Empty ? 

I'm trying it now, will let you know soon.

Comment: It is a crappy internal Excel error.  You'll get a million google hits when you query for "excel error 1004", best to start at the top.

Comment: @DJKRAZE Now i got the same error, but right on the .Open line. 

Any thoughts?

Comment: depends on how you declared your FilePath

Comment: Something like this : C:\Projetos\Marcello Lins\TIM\Relatorios_Cobranca\AcompanhamentoPagamentosDiaXDia\PagamentosDiaXDiaLib\Report\report.xlsx

Comment: can you post that code in your original question I would need to see exactly the flow of code also what version cof Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel are you using..?

Comment: I just tested the code that opens and I have no problems I can post a snippet of what I am doing in the Answer section and you can kind of use that as a guide if you like notice how I am creating the excel application and the workbooks as well

Comment: @DJKRAZE I was copying the initialization code wrong, it works now, but i still got the same error as before, on the same line. I updated the question adding my Interop wrapper

Comment: I will remove my Answer Example I think that you need to change the foreach on the workbook to a for loop then as well as how you are instantiating the WorkSheets and particular WorkSheet that you are working on

Comment: Will you provide me any insights with a new answer?